# Filter w/ seemingly higher output voltage than input?

Tags: voltage, rf, filter, voltage-divider, basic

I'm working on a simple LC filter as part of an AM radio project. I was intending to use a ferrite antenna (modeled roughly by the voltage source in series w/ inductor which is then connected to a capacitor that will be parallel to the rest of the circuit), but according to my simulations and calculations [the output voltage not only peaks at w0, but peaks higher than then input voltage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TEDms.jpg) which seems conceptually impossible to me. Is this right or am I missing something?

Comment: That's entirely possible with resonance.

Comment: See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RLC_circuit#Sinusoidal_steady_state

Comment: Keep in mind that a **gain** in voltage is accompanied by a **loss** of current in a passive-component circuit (L&C).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That is common behavior for a resonant LC circuit.

Near resonance, the input impedance nears zero, because the capacitive reactance is equal and opposite from the inductive reactance (\$X_C\approx-X_L\$). Therefore even a small input voltage can produce a large current through the LC series combination. However the voltage across each individual element in the circuit is still \$V=jIX\$, so the voltage across each element can be larger than the input voltage.

It may be more accurate to model the source in your antenna as a current source rather than a voltage source, and to include a loading effect due to whatever circuit the antenna is feeding.